# Use importdata without renaming the file extension to .txt

Tags: matlab, import

I like the command **importdata**, but it does not work on my files without me renaming the file extension to *.txt* (or removing the file extension) before importing.

This problem only occurs when I am running Matlab 2014b, the other versions seem to act as predicted.

I can open the files in any standard text editor, so the file format should be understandable for Matlab (I think). The extension may for example be *.res*, *.ida*, or other "custom" extension names ...

Can I get Matlab to understand how to treat the file as a *.txt* without renaming it? Or any other workaround (that would be a few lines short as **importdata**)??

Example file:

text text text text
text 11 12 13
text 21 22 23

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It isn't true that `importdata` only works on `*.txt` files. If it is not a standard file format it will treat it as a delimited ASCII file. What's likely happening is that the built in helper functions cannot detect the structure of your file. What is the format of the data? Space delimited, tab delimited, some other delimiter? Are there headers? For generic options, see MATLAB's [documentation for importing and exporting data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html), specifically the 'Standard File Formats' and 'Low-Level File I/O' sections.

Comment: There is both text (a few lines) and then a matrix. Delimited with space. Using the **importdata** is convenient since it separates the data and textdata automatically.

Comment: Without a functioning example that reproduces your issue it is difficult to assist with your problem. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: Okay, I will do that when I have access to Matlab.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding it to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file can have any extension you want. just specify the delimiter, in your case a space

```
my_delim = ' ';
M = importdata(any_file_type_with_text_in_it, my_delim):
```

Comment: This did not work, I still receive an empty array. So then I got suspicious and tried Matlab (2011) on Windows and it works, and so does an older version in Gnome (2012b). It is the version I am currently using (2014b) that does not work (using Gnome) for some reason... This is a problem since I am using new functionality that released 2014. Which version did you test with?

Comment: I used 2012a (which i feel is old enough as it is) with windows and mac. Maybe it is a linux distro problem then? I'm not sure your desktop type (gnome, kde, etc) would make a difference, since they all get the same java distro. Can you try a 2014 windows machine?

Comment: No, I do not have that version installed in Windows.

Comment: have you looked at line endings in your file? maybe there is a mix of `cr` and `lf` that the parser in `importdata` doesn't like. Just a guess, I'm not sure what else it would be. good luck